# isset invocation gets last variable value

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a PHP class called `Question`. Inside `Question` is a public variable called `$q_id`.

```
class Question{
        public $url;
        public $q_id;

        function __construct(){
            global $db;
            $this->url = $_GET["url"];


            $result = $db->query("SELECT q_id FROM wyr_questions WHERE `url` = '$this->url'");

            if ($result->num_rows == 0){
                header('Location: 404');
                die();
            }

            else{
                $row = $result->fetch_array();

                $this->q_id = $row["q_id"];

            }
        }
$user = new Question();
```

Now I have 2 buttons, a dislike and a like button. When the user presses the like or dislike button, a `$_POST` method is invoked. The `isset` method is outside of the class and underneath the `$user` object.

```
if (isset($_POST["like"])){
        $q_id = $user->q_id;

        if ($_POST["like"] == 1){
            $db->query("UPDATE wyr_questions SET thumbs_up = thumbs_up + 1 WHERE `q_id` = '$user->q_id'"); 

        }

        else{
            $db->query("UPDATE wyr_questions SET thumbs_down = thumbs_down+1 WHERE `q_id` = '$q_id'");    

       }
}
```

Now every time I click the like button, the number of likes are updated based on what the last `q_id` was. For example, let's say I liked `q_id: 29` and then moved to like `q_id: 30` then the query in `isset($_POST["like"])` will update the number of likes for `q_id: 29` and not `q_id: 30` Why is it updating the previous `q_id` and not the current `q_id`?

Comment: You should use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid sql injection ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just move your code

```
$user = new Question();
```

inside the isset invocation.

something like this:

```
class Question{
    public $url;
    public $q_id;

    function __construct(){
        global $db;
        $this->url = $_GET["url"];


        $result = $db->query("SELECT q_id FROM wyr_questions WHERE `url` = '$this->url'");

        if ($result->num_rows == 0){
            header('Location: 404');
            die();
        }

        else{
            $row = $result->fetch_array();

            $this->q_id = $row["q_id"];

        }
    }

if (isset($_POST["like"])){
    $user = new Question(); //here is the new position of this code
    $q_id = $user->q_id;

    if ($_POST["like"] == 1){
        $db->query("UPDATE wyr_questions SET thumbs_up = thumbs_up + 1 WHERE `q_id` = '$user->q_id'"); 

    }

    else{
        $db->query("UPDATE wyr_questions SET thumbs_down = thumbs_down+1 WHERE `q_id` = '$q_id'");    

   }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, even with that I am still getting the previous `q_id` instead of the current one.

Comment: What is the content of your url?

Comment: url is a column name in my table. It'll first check if the url exists or not, if it doesn't then we display a 404 error. When I echo the q_id out in an HTML p tag, then the correct q_id is displayed. For example: `<p><?php echo $user->q_id; ?></p>`

Comment: I think it is because your select query is inside the construct function.. try to move it out